# Windows Phone 8 Webbrowser (zoom)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8 app, but I'm stuck at the last part...
It's an app to view the calendars on school: [see calendar](https://kalender.phl.be/kalenterit2/index.php?av_v=&av=131118131124131120&cluokka=2TINF&kt=lk&laji=&guest=IT/phl&lang=fla&ui=&yks=&apvm=131118&tiedot=kaikki&ss_ttkal=&ccv=&yhopt=&__cm=&b=1384974598&av_y=0)
Now I open the link of every class (I have the changes for every class, but it opens small... What can I do to solve this ? (See picture) + I can't acces the website codes.

See the picture:

[image]

I only want the calendar of the website and not the rest at the left side.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want people to HELP you solve problems here, then you need to post example code. (Most of us) are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:300%;";
    }
```

assuming webBrowser1 is the name of your control

Comment: My app is ready, the only thing that isn't working is the standard zoom... (see picture in first post)